# AWS CDK Code Pipelines- Why Can Local Obtain The Branch But Code Build Cannot?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

My goal is to dynamically name resources to allow for multiple environments. For example, a "dev-accounts" table, and a "prod-accounts" table.

**The issue** I am facing is Code Build cannot dynamically name resources, whilst local can. Following the example above, I am receiving "undefined-accounts" when viewing the logs in Code Build.

**Code to obtain the environment by branch name:**

```
export const getContext = (app: App): Promise<CDKContext> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const currentBranch = await gitBranch();
            const environment = app.node.tryGetContext("environments").find((e: any) => e.branchName === currentBranch);
            const globals = app.node.tryGetContext("globals");
            return resolve({...globals, ...environment});
        }
        catch (error) {
            return reject("Cannot get context from getContext()");
        }
    })
}
```

**Further Explanation:**

In the `bin/template.ts` file, I am using `console.log` to log the context, after calling `const context = await getContext(app);`

Local CLI outcome:

```
{
  appName: 'appName',
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  accountId: '000000000',
  environment: 'dev',
  branchName: 'dev'
}
```

Code Build outcome:

```
{
  appName: 'appName',
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  accountId: '000000000'
}
```

*Note I've removed sensitive information.*

**This is my Code Pipeline built in the CDK:**

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true
    }),
    installCommands: ["npm i -g npm@latest"],
    commands: [
      "cd backend",
      "npm ci",
      "npm run build",
      "cdk synth",
    ],
    primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
  })
});
```

By using the key/value `codeBuildCloneOutput: true`, I believe I am completing a full clone of Code Commit repository, and thus the git metadata.

Comment: What is the value of `currentBranch` when run cloud-side?

Comment: @fedonev, how would I determine this?

Comment: Just `console.log` it.  My guess is that it's `undefined`.  While you're at it, add a `ls -a` command  before you `cd backend`.  You're looking for `.git`.  Or, if you just want a built-in way to get the branch name, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeBuild exposes the `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html). For CodeCommit, this is *"the commit ID or branch name associated with the version of the source code to be built"*.

```js
const currentBranch = process.env.CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION ?? await gitBranch();
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the CDK Stack?

Comment: I've tried `env: { ["CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION"] : branchName },` but the error showed of `No user environment variables can start with CODEBUILD_`

Comment: @Luke CodeBuild sets the value.  You consume the value. See the edited answer.

Comment: Looking at this again.... `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` exists and has a value of `'arn:aws:s3:::dev-pipeline-stack....`, whereas `const currentBranch = await gitBranch();` returns `null`. I'm expecting to obtain `dev`. I don't believe this solution works.

Comment: @Luke  The point is once you have the branch name ARN from the env var, your code can parse it to extract whatever value you need.  Use regex.  Or a switch statement.  Or another method.  That implementation detail is no longer related to the question.